# Заполнение массива и двумерного массива с клавиатуры

Tags: java, массивы

Не работает цикл if чтобы выбрать вид массива и заполнить его

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fourth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Введите вид массива 1 - обычный, 2 - двумерный: ");
            int a = input.nextInt();
            
                if (a == 1)                     
                    System.out.print("Введите длинну массива: ");
                int size = input.nextInt(); 
                int array[] = new int[size];
                System.out.print("Введите элемент массива:");
            
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    array[i] = input.nextInt(); 
                }
                System.out.print ("\nДлинна массива: " + array.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    System.out.print (" \n" + array[i]); 
                }
                System.out.println();   
                if (a == 2) {
             
                System.out.print("Введите количество строк массива: ");
                int c = input.nextInt();
                        
                System.out.print("Введите количество столбцов массива: ");
                int d = input.nextInt();
               
                
                int[][] arr = new int[c][d];
                
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("Введите элемент arr[" + i + "][" + j + "]:");
                 arr[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                    }   
                        }
                    }
                    


    }
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос низкого качества. Ознакомьтесь с информацией из справки [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В `Java` после `if` надо ставить `{` если потом идет несколько "действий":

`{` после `if` можно **не** ставить только если потом идет 1 действие

#### Примеры:

Код:

```
int a = 1;
if(a == 1) System.out.println("Hello");
System.out.println("world");
```

Вывод:

```
Hello
world
```

---

Код:

```
int a = 0;
if(a == 1) System.out.println("Hello");
System.out.println("world");
```

Вывод:

```
world
```

---

Код:

```
int a = 1;
if(a == 1) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    System.out.println("world");
}
```

Вывод:

```
Hello
world
```

---

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите вид массива 1 - обычный, 2 - двумерный: ");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        
        if (a == 1) {                    
            System.out.print("Введите длинну массива: ");
            int size = input.nextInt(); 
            int array[] = new int[size];
            System.out.print("Введите элемент массива:");
            ...
        } else if(a == 2) {
            ...
        }
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите вид массива 1 - обычный, 2 - двумерный: ");
        int a = input.nextInt();

        if (a == 1) {
            System.out.print("Введите длинну массива: ");
            int size = input.nextInt();
            int[] array = new int[size];
            System.out.print("Введите элемент массива:");

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                array[i] = input.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.print("\nДлинна массива: " + array.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                System.out.print(" \n" + array[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        else if (a == 2) {

            System.out.print("Введите количество строк массива: ");
            int c = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Введите количество столбцов массива: ");
            int d = input.nextInt();


            int[][] arr = new int[c][d];

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print("Введите элемент arr[" + i + "][" + j + "]:");
                    arr[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]